# Make AlarmManager trigger service to update db

Tags: android, kotlin, service, retrofit2, alarmmanager

So i'm trying to run a service that sends certain room data to a server every midnight(roughly) and deletes it from the local db. Reading the android docs i came to the conclusion that the best approach currently was to setup an alarm that triggers at midnight and starts a Service that executes the syncing). While i'm not entirely sure of what type of Service i should i use my files look like this:

MainActivity.kt

```
    alarmMgr = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager?

    alarmIntent = Intent(this, SendTakesReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }


    // Set the alarm to send takes at approximately 00:00 a.m.
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    }


    // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
    // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
    alarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        alarmIntent
    )
```

SendtakesReceiver.kt

```
class SendTakesReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            //these following logs are always shown
            Log.d("TAKES INTENT", intent.toString())

            if (intent != null) {
                context?.run {
                    Log.d("TAKES SERVICE", intent.toString())
                    startService(intent)
                }
            }

        }
}
```

SendTakesService.kt

```
class SendTakesService : Service() {
        val sp: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        private var prescriptionTakeDao =
                      AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).prescriptionTakeDao()


        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            Log.d("TakesService", "onCreate()")
        }

        override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
            return null
        }
}
```

And finally in my manifest file i have (inside the application tag):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".src.ui.prescriptions.SendTakesReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" />

<service
    android:name="com.glik.glik.src.services.SendTakesService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":SendTakes">
</service>
```

But the problem is that none of the service Classes(Service, IntentService, JobIntentService) that i've tried using are calling their main method. For example here the `onCreate()` log is never shown. I've seen countless of similar questions regarding services not being started but i can't seem to pinpoint the exact mistake that i am making here that causes the service to not be started. If any one could help me find it or maybe recommend a more elegant approach to do the db sync i would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Service won't run in Android 8 and above, you need to use foreground service.

Comment: That's true. I changed my receiver to check if it should run a foregroundservice or not but the `onCreate` method is still not being called

Comment: You need to send a notification to run foreground service. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OEM of the phone you are on, you will face various challenges with this approach. See https://dontkillmyapp.com/

[You should use WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#features) in order to decrease battery usage and to avoid having to manually handle many corner cases: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics